# Can the same Serverless VPC Connector be used for two different App Engine standard instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm working with a cost-conscious client, trying to avoid having to spin up more Serverless VPC Connector-machines just to handle the dev environment.

We are using static IPs for outbound traffic, having followed this guide: [App Engine Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/outbound-ip-addresses), but we need prod and dev to use different IP addresses.

Is it possible to use the same Serverless VPC Connector and somehow route or restrict the App Engine instance to a specific subnet, NAT or Cloud Router? As far as I can tell, the standard environment app.yaml only allows us to set

```
vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/connectors/CONNECTOR_NAME
  egress_setting: all-traffic
```

and since our VPC Connector is specific to a subnet, I don't see a way through this.

Comment: Does this threads help you?: [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837061/18265570) & [thread2](https://serverfault.com/a/977254/955887)